# {{ @require_once(@resource_path()) }} causes a random 1 string character to be outputted in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have tried looking for the character with `ctrl + f`, I checked my `web.php`, checked the layouts file and the file itself. Nowhere do I output the character 1 (`"1 "`).
I emptied the file and then tried it again, it returns the `"1 "`. I tried it with other files, same. The only time it does not happen is when I completely remove `{{ @require_once(@resource_path("views/includes/myFile.blade.php)) }}`. The character is printed on every page as well.

This is how my `layout.blade.php` file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <title>
            layout Component
        </title>

        @yield("head_css")

        @yield("head_js")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
               {{ @require_once(@resource_path("views/Includes/navigation.blade.php")) }}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @yield("body_content")
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                @yield("footer")
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is how my `navigation.blade.php` looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    hello
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
                        <option>a</option>
                        <option>b</option>
                    </select>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you are echoing the return value of `require_once` which is `1` in this case ... not sure why you are throwing `@` in front of things ... if you want to "include" a view you would use the `@include` directive

Comment: @lagbox because I am new to laravel and merely trying stuff out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has multiple issues:

```
{{ @require_once(@resource_path("views/Includes/navigation.blade.php")) }}
```

1. The curly braces are for outputting data, like an *echo* statement. Additionally it encodes HTML entities, which you definitely don't want. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#including-subviews.
2. It looks like you are trying to include another blade view file that is already inside your views path. You should be able then to use the `@include` directive as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#including-subviews.

So I think you want to do something like this:

```
@include("Includes.navigation"))
```